# Disabling share charm shortcut Win 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, shortcuts

I've disabled Win+L key by creating a registry key DisableLockWorkstation on Windows 10, and I'd like to do the same with the Win+H shortcut which launches share sideboard, can this be done in the same way I did with the other windows shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a registry key to block that one hotkey (One exists to block all <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>__</kbd> hotkeys though)

One solution to block just the one though, using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), you can create the following script:

```
#h::
return
```

When this is running, it cancels the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> hotkey, but it does require this third party software.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jonno, I know of autohotkey, and that is exactly why I was asking the question. I'm using Win+H as a browser shortcut, and it works, but I have another script which is supposed to open my browser, that is, it sends Win+H key as part of the sequence of commands. For some reason, it doesn't launch browser at that point, but instead opens the default Share charm sidebar. It seems that the only solution would be to disable the default Win+H shortcut in the windows registry. 
It doesn't help that I also added a registry key which in theory should disable each Windows button shortcut. For some reason it doesn't work for certain key combinations.